# Google Cloud SQL graph not reporting across multiple servers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have multiple Cloud SQL servers all with broken reporting. Examples below. All reporting massive gaps. I have logged out, refreshed the page, used multiple browsers, and they're all reporting the same graph. Data hasn't been restricted from the SQL servers, nothing in their logs, seems to be an issue on Google's side, but the status page for GCP is all green at the moment. Note that this seems to be only on Cloud SQL, not any of my compute servers.

[image: replica-1]

[image: replica-2]

[image: master]

Comment: I have seen this before. The next day no problems. I am not sure what the lag time is for these graphs, but it is not "instantaneous". Double-check that you are not low on free disk space on Cloud SQL. If you are, increase the disk size so that there is room for your logs.

Comment: I should also add that I have a new Cloud SQL master with the same issue. But to your point, all Cloud SQL servers have plenty of space remaining.

Comment: Wait until about 18+ hours have passed since the problem started. If not resolved, open an Issue. Issues can be converted to private so that Google engineers can request private information like the Cloud SQL Instance ID: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: Thank you, @JohnHanley, I'll check back in a few hours to see if it's still an issue.

Comment: It is a known internal issue regarding this. Could you try to restart your Cloud SQL instances and see if the issue is persistent after that? I am waiting for your response.

Comment: I had restarted several times during that gap, to no change. It did, however, come back at 23:59 UTC across all Cloud SQL servers. Nothing is planned (backups, maintenance, etc) until several hours after 00:00, so it wasn't some process that 'kickstarted' it back to life. Perplexing, but glad it is now back.